# Fit text into svg without using js

Tags: svg

It is necessary that the text fills the svg as much as possible as with `bacground-size: contain`. The svg parent can be resized dynamically. The text is always single line. Now such a solution is used using js, but it is desirable to do it using the svg itself.

```js
const $svg = document.querySelector(`svg`);
const $text = $svg.querySelector('text');
const $input = document.querySelector('input');

$input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  $text.textContent = e.target.value;
  const box = $text.getBBox();
  $svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
});

$input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
<text alignment-baseline="baseline" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"></text>
</svg>
<input type='text' value='Random single line text'>
```

Comment: CSS Tricks did a [post](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) on this a few years back, not sure that anything has changed since. It's pretty much either magic numbers or Javascript, if you want dynamic then you need JS, why would you not want to use JS though?

Comment: Paul answered that one a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298838/svg-responsive-text

Comment: This answer not work with very long or short text.
CSS Tricks use magick number, this now work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a parent `div`? Add a no wrap attribute (`word-break` or `flex-wrap` for a flex container) to the text and that will stretch the `div` to full text width. Then make the `svg` `width: 100%` within the `div`.

Comment: Stretch div dont change font size.

Comment: No it doesn't, I'm getting what you want wrong here. Did you not just want the text to fill the svg? So resizing svg helps. Or you mean you want the text to resize, and the user controls how big the svg is?

Comment: The text should fill as much of the svg as possible.